# Getting appropriate storage value type?

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose we have a class Box as follows:

```
struct Base {}

template<typename T>
struct Box : Base
{
    template<typename... Args>
    Box(Args&&... args)
        : t(forward<Args>(args)...)
    {}

    T t;
}
```

And then we have a function MakeBox:

```
template<typename X>
Base* MakeBox(X&& x)
{
    return new Box<???>(forward<X>(x));
}
```

The type `X` is deduced from the parameter used in the call to MakeBox.

We then need to calculate somehow from X the appropriate "storage type" parameter T.

I think if we just naively use:

```
    return new Box<X>(forward<X>(x));
```

then this will cause problems.

Clearly `std::bind` and `std::function` need to deal with these problems, how do they do it?

Is `std::decay` helpful in anyway here?

Comment: Isn't [`std::remove_reference<X>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference) what you are looking for?

Comment: @jogojapan: Is that what `std::bind` uses to store its bound parameters?

Comment: `std::decay` is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: So it's `return new Box<decay<X>::type>(forward<X>(x))`?  The `std::decay` docs say "This is the type conversion applied to all function arguments when passed by value.".  I am not sure I understand exactly what that means.

Comment: Is the question about how `bind` works and what auxiliary functions it uses (which clearly depends on the implementation), or about how to deal with the situation in your code?

Comment: @jogojapan: The question is, from a deduced "universal reference" `X&& x` how can we calculate an appropriate type `T` with which to store `x`.

Comment: Here is the final class relating to this question: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/20058/a-c11-any-class

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly what you want to achieve, then you need to use `std::decay`. Supposing you are supplying an object of type `S` to `MakeBox()`, the universal reference `X&&` will be resolved in such a way to make the function argument either of type `S&` or `S&&` depending on whether your argument is (respectively) an lvalue or an rvalue.

To achieve this and due to C++11 rules for universal references, in the first case the template argument will be deduced as `X=S&` (here `X` would not be OK as an argument to `Box<>`, because your member variable has to be an object and not an object reference), while in the second case it will be deduced as `X=S` (here `X` would be fine as an argument to `Box<>`). By applying `std::decay` you will also implicitly apply `std::remove_reference` to the deduced type `X` before supplying it as a template argument to `Box<>`, you are going to make sure that `X` will always be equal `S` and never `S&` (please keep in mind, that `X` is *never* going to be deduced as `S&&` here, it will be either `S` or `S&`).

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Base {};

template<typename T>
struct Box : Base
{
    template<typename... Args>
    Box(Args&&... args)
        : t(forward<Args>(args)...)
    {
    }

    T t;
};

template<typename X>
Base* MakeBox(X&& x)
{
    return new Box<typename decay<X>::type>(forward<X>(x));
}

struct S
{
    S() { cout << "Default constructor" << endl; }
    S(S const& s) { cout << "Copy constructor" << endl; }
    S(S&& s) { cout << "Move constructor" << endl; }
    ~S() { cout << "Destructor" << endl; }
};

S foo()
{
    S s;
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    S s;

    // Invoking with lvalue, will deduce X=S&, argument will be of type S&
    MakeBox(s);

    // Invoking with rvalue, will deduce X=S, argument will be of type S&&
    MakeBox(foo());

    return 0;
}
```

If you are interested, here is a very good lesson by Scott Meyers where he explains how universal references behave:

[Scott Meyers on universal references](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Scott-Meyers-Universal-References-in-Cpp11)

P.S.: **This answer has been edited**: my original answer suggested to use `std::remove_reference<>`, but `std::decay` turned out to be a better choice. Credits to the question poster @Andrew Tomazos FathomlingCorps, who pointed that out, and to @Mankarse, who first proposed it in a comment to the original question.

Comment: Indeed `std::decay` seems to be a good option, probably even better because it does include `std::remove_reference<>` as well. The reason why I did not consider it in the beginning is that it strips away the `const` qualifier, but then I realized you probably don't want to keep the `const` qualifier at all, since you are creating a new object inside of `Box` and calling its copy constructor. If so, we can indeed replace `std::remove_reference` with `std::decay` in my answer. I will do that and give proper credit.

Comment: Btw, concerning function `MakeBox<>()` and class `Box<>`, are you sure you always want to call just the copy constructor of `T` all the time? You have an argument pack in the constructor of `Box<>` to forward the arguments to the constructor of `T`, but you are always passing just one `T` object in input so it always invokes the copy constructor. Shouldn't you have a variadic list also in `MakeBox<>()`? Btw, instead of returning a Base* I would return the exact pointer (`Box<typename std::decay<T>::type>*`)

Comment: I think `typename decay<typename remove_reference<T>::type>::type;` is redundant there, as `decay<>` already includes `remove_reference<>`. See here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay

Answer (score 1):

For the provided example `(1)` does what you want and stores the value. For other cases (such as when `x` is an array) you can use `std::decay` to decay it to a pointer and store that.